# What CPU architectures are supported by Ubuntu Core

Tags: ubuntu-core

Here are the following hardware platform mentioned in ubuntu core docs. https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/#platforms

Here is the doc for board enablement.
https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/build-device/board-enablement

So, can I use custom development board to boot ubuntu core? Such as this system on a chip https://www.solid-run.com/product/SRI8000S00D04GE008Q00CH

Or this board https://developer.toradex.com/products/apalis-t30

If I can, what would be the steps? As far as I understood, May be I have to customize meta snap yaml like the following:
for (https://www.solid-run.com/product/SRI8000S00D04GE008Q00CH)

```
name: the-name-i-want-to-put
version: 18.04-1
summary: Support package for <my board architecture>
description: |
 Support files for booting <board name>
type: gadget
architectures:
    - amd64
```

original meta/snap.yml - 
https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/build-device/board-enablement#metasnapyaml-example